# Java logarithm by log(num, base)(Closed)

Tags: java, android, math, logarithm

I am making a program with android SDK (Java), but I have GUIed my program to which you get a number, then the base. The base can be an any number. Do I have a way other than to switch-case it infinitely? 
(I have closed this thread. I have found that logb(x)=log10(x)/log10(b))

Comment: please be clear i am unable to understand your problem

Comment: Give more details. Your problem is unclear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is where maths can help to work it out ;)

[image]

This allows you to calculate the log in any base.

```
public static double log(double value, double base) {
    return Math.log(value)/Math.log(base);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your issue is,

but you can get value directly after pressing button (no switch/case needed)

```
Button   mButton;
EditText base,num;
int iBase,iNum;

/** Called activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    base   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_base);
    num    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_num);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                iNum = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
                iBase = Integer.parseInt(base.getText().toString());
                Log.v("Result", Math.Log(iNum)/Math.Log("iBase"));
            }
        });
}
```